# new Class().Function() pattern

Tags: c#

I am maintaining an application and have seen something like this

```
Permission p = new UserModel().GetPermission(userToTestPerrmission, permissionWeCheck);
if(p.CanChange)
   //sometihing
else
   //something else
```

This approach looks a little "dirty" to me. The part I have problems with is this `new UserModel().GetPermission()`. Is this a typical way to write something like this or should it be like:

```
var model = new UserModel();
model.GetPermissions(...);
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a typical way to write something like

If that’s all the information that is required – yes, why not? I see no problem at all with this approach.

On the other hand, if code lik this is prolific this is a sure sign that the original class design is broken. But from your code it looks like this is outside of your control anyway, since `UserModel` is a framework class.

In general, if a class is used in such a fashion then it is over-engineered: a static method could have been used just as well (on the other hand, this may make unit testing harder because it prevents mocking).

Comment: Nicely said. If a class is used for initialization and a method call, why is it a class in the first place? (of course, this is harder to obey in a purely OO language, which quite further proves that OOP is not a silver bullet)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this does stink. Consider the following:

```
byte[] data = { ... };

File.OpenWrite("filename.dat").Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

`File.OpenWrite` implements `IDisposable` and therefore should be deterministically disposed as such:

```
byte[] data = { ... };

using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("filename.dat"))
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

So, keep an eye out.